# How to convert NSData variable into NSInteger variable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsdata

I have the following api method which returns **NSData**. I have called this method in another view controller. How to convert the **NSData** to **NSInteger**?

```
-(NSData *)getBusXMLAtStop:(NSString*)stopnumber
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: 
                                    [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000",stopnumber]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
    dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",dataReply);
    return dataReply;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    api *ap = [[api alloc]init];
    NSData *str = [ap getBusXMLAtStop:@"1"];
    // Here is where I want to convert str into NSInteger type. How is this possible?
    NSLog(@"this is success %@",ap.dataReply);
    TWeatherParser *parser = [[TWeatherParser alloc]init];
    [parser getInitialiseWithData:ap.dataReply];
    [parser release];
    [ap release];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you know that your data is really representing a single integer, the simplest way is the following:

```
NSData *data = ...;
int i;
[data getBytes: &i length: sizeof(i)];
```

UPD: `NSInteger` is defined depending on the architecture of the target processor and is either `int` or `long`. Feel free to replace `int` by `NSInteger` in the code above.

I'm also not sure that your data is an actual number and not it's string representation. In this case use something like

```
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:(encoding you need)] autorelease];
NSInteger value = [str intValue];
```

Comment: but method is returning NSData so i have doubt that whether it will not create any issue when i will convert it directly to nsstring variable.Thanks

Comment: i have written your code NSString *str = [NSString stringWithData:aData encoding: (encoding you need) ];
NSInteger value = [str intValue]; but it gives me warning that NSString may not respond to stringWithData

Answer (score 0):

You can find a convenience initialiser on `NSString` called `initWithData:`. Please check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416374-initwithdata?language=objc) for more info.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
NSString * s = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```